# How to remove table view from a XIB?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I would like to create a navigation based application without the Table View stuff... when I select "navigation based application" at the project start, I get a Root view that inherits from UITableViewController... I wish to inherit from UINavigationController and delete all the table methods in the implementation file... question is...

how do I change the XIB in interface builder to give a simple UIView rather than UITableView?

please and thank you

Comment: Open it up, delete the `UITableView` and drag in a `UIView`? Seems fairly logical to me.

Comment: Sounds like you're pretty new to interface builder and xcode. The Apple iOS developer center site has tones of get-started material that will answer these simple questions.

Answer (score 4):

In the Objects list, select the TableView, press Delete.

[image]

Then drag in whatever type of view you want, like a NavBar controller.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple, but some people forget a few steps.

1. delete the table view
2. add a view
3. make sure to wire up the outlet for the viewcontroller.view
4. in the .h file change the super class to view controller, rather than tableview controller.

Answer (score 0):

First Delete the UITableView from .xib then add the view in .xib and delete the UITableViewController from .h class and edit it with UIViewController.